# Best language/library to use Bayesian Network in production

Tags: bayesian-network

I'm looking for the best language and library to use Bayesian Networks in production. I need the model to be sufficiently fast for an almost real time experience. The computation load is to update the model from about 10 new data points each time a user will make a request and the user shouldn't wait more than about 2 seconds. It seems like there is a lot of libraries in R but R has a bad reputation for production, while Python has a better reputation but less expertise/libraries for Bayesian Networks.

What's best ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are three major (modern) libraries for Bayesian Inference in Python - PyStan, PyMC3 and Edward.

All 3 should be pretty fast, as PyStan compiles into C++, PyMC3 was built on top of Theano, and Edward on top of Tensorflow.

Of the three, PyMC3 has the easiest-to-learn syntax, but is allegedly somewhat computationally unreliable at times.

For PyStan you will have to learn a clunky language (the original Stan language), but it's very well documented.

I personally like Edward best, but it requires knowledge of variational inference (thus making it harder to maintain from a commercial standpoint), as you will need to specify cavity distributions for inference.

PyStan probably has the largest developer community within academia, PyMC3 has a pretty strong following too. Not too sure about the size of Edward community (since it's quite new), but its forum shows it's very active.

Comment: I should also add that only Edward seems to be able to fully harness the computational power of GPU. PyMC3 only uses GPU for matrix computations, not inference.